# "SQL command not properly ended" SEQUENCE Creation Random Error

Tags: sql, oracle

Was creating a sequence that basically auto increments by 10. Tried to run it, but it gave the error

> SQL command not properly ended

Not sure where I went gone wrong here, and I've been at this problem for a while, analyzing for spelling errors, adding commas even though sequence creations for oracle don't need commas, checking for spaces, etc. Yet no success.

What exactly is the problem with this code?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE emplevel_seq
MINVALUE 1
NO MAXVALUE
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 10
CACHE 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html#GUID-E9C78A8C-615A-4757-B2A8-5E6EFB130571) is:

> [image: CREATE SEQUENCE syntax]

You want `NOMAXVALUE` rather than `NO MAXVALUE`.

Comment: Tried it and it worked, thank you man. Weird part about the "NO MAXVALUE" bit is that I found it like that on some Oracle SQL explanation site. Thanks for showcasing the entire diagram relating to the commands though

Comment: _"Thanks for showcasing the entire diagram relating to the commands"_  Hopefully this will have taught you the value of checking the documentation yourself.